# Cursor with same query returning different result

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I am saving a marker in `SQLite` with this method :

```
 public long addMarker(Markers marker) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=null;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, marker.get_address());
        values.put(COLUMN_COUNTRY, marker.get_country());
        values.put(COLUMN_LAT, marker.get_lat());
        values.put(COLUMN_LNG, marker.get_lng());
        values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, marker.get_image());
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values);
        if (result>0){
            db.close();
        }
        return result;
}
```

then `onMarkerClick` i must get all the info for the marker i clicked using `LatLng` for arguments.
This is the method i use:

```
public Markers getOneMarker(double lat, double lng) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor curs = db.query(true,TABLE_LOCATIONS,new String[]{COLUMN_ID,
            COLUMN_ADDRESS,COLUMN_COUNTRY,
            COLUMN_LAT,COLUMN_LNG,COLUMN_IMAGE},
            COLUMN_LAT+"="+lat+" AND "+COLUMN_LNG+"="+lng,
            null,null,null,null,null);
    Markers marker = null;
    if (curs != null) {
        curs.moveToFirst();
        try{
            marker = new Markers(Integer.valueOf(curs.getString(0)),curs.getString(1), curs.getString(2),Double.valueOf(curs.getString(3)),Double.valueOf(curs.getString(4)),curs.getString(5));
        }catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            marker = new Markers("Address for location unavailable ", "N/A", lat, lng, "image");
        }

    }
    assert curs != null;
    curs.close();
    db.close();
    return marker;
}
```

90% of the times i got what i want(address and country name) but the other 10% i get `"Address for location unavailable ", "N/A"`. I made a `Toast` in the `onClick()`to check the Geocoder but its ok. I am getting an address but not from the db. Any ideas?
Edit: Is it possible to be a sync issue? if it is so how to open the marker AFTER it is saved in the DB.
Saving in DB is called in async task class in `onPostExecute()`
This is my `DatabaseHandler` class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static DatabaseHandler sInstance;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "locations.db";
public static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "_address";
public static final String COLUMN_COUNTRY = "_country";
public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "_lat";
public static final String COLUMN_LNG = "_lng";
public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "_image";




private DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
public static synchronized DatabaseHandler getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_COUNTRY + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_LAT + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_LNG + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_IMAGE + " TEXT " +
            ");";

    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATIONS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public long addMarker(Markers marker) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, marker.get_address());
        values.put(COLUMN_COUNTRY, marker.get_country());
        values.put(COLUMN_LAT, marker.get_lat());
        values.put(COLUMN_LNG, marker.get_lng());
        values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, marker.get_image());
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values);
        if (result>0){
            db.close();
        }
        return result;
}

public void deleteMarker(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=\"" + id + "\";");
}

public Markers getOneMarker(double lat, double lng) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor curs = db.query(true,TABLE_LOCATIONS,new String[]{COLUMN_ID,
            COLUMN_ADDRESS,COLUMN_COUNTRY,
            COLUMN_LAT,COLUMN_LNG,COLUMN_IMAGE},
            COLUMN_LAT+"="+lat+" AND "+COLUMN_LNG+"="+lng,
            null,null,null,null,null);
    Markers marker = null;
    if( curs != null && curs.moveToFirst() && curs.getCount() >= 1 ){
        do{
            try{
                marker = new Markers(Integer.valueOf(curs.getString(0)),curs.getString(1), curs.getString(2),Double.valueOf(curs.getString(3)),Double.valueOf(curs.getString(4)),curs.getString(5));

            }catch(CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                marker = new Markers("Address for location unavailable ", "N/A", lat, lng, "image");
            }


        } while(curs.moveToNext());
    }
    if (curs != null) {
        curs.close();
    }
    db.close();
public void updateMarker(int id,String link){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE "+TABLE_LOCATIONS + " SET "+ COLUMN_IMAGE + "="+link+" WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=\"" + id + "\";";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
public int getID(double lat, double lng){
    Markers marker = getOneMarker(lat,lng);
    return marker.get_id();
}
```

}
This is the method in the `Activity` where i call it:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MarkerActivity.class);
        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        Markers tempMarker = databaseHandler.getOneMarker(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude);
        addressLine = tempMarker.get_address();
        country = tempMarker.get_country();
        String lat = String.valueOf(tempMarker.get_lat());
        String lng = String.valueOf(tempMarker.get_lng());
        intent.putExtra("address", addressLine);
        intent.putExtra("country", country);
        intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
        intent.putExtra("lng", lng);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return true;
}
```

And the method i save them with:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Markers markers) {
        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        id = databaseHandler.addMarker(markers);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onPostExecute(markers);
        markerList.add(latLng);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Suggestions:

Best way to get information from cursor is,

```
if( curs != null && curs.moveToFirst() && curs.getCount() >= 1 ){
    do {
        ....
    } while( curs.moveToNext() );
}
```

#### Designing Singletone SQLiteHelper

If you are using multi threaded processing (For example `AsyncTask` in your project), It is best practice to use `SQLite` database access in `Singletone` manner. That means you need to design you `DatabaseHelper` class like below,

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

  private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
  private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table_name";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  ...
  public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
   * make call to static method "getInstance()" instead.
   */
  private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
}
```

#### Accessing database

Now in all over your project when you need to open your database helper, you have to access like,

```
DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
```

Comment: now i am getting NullPointer when `getAddress` is called on the db object. Precentage maybe went to 95%. "Address for location unavailable " is no longer showing but now its nullPointer

Comment: Still getting the same null pointer. Toast still printing correct string. I am still using `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();` in the `getOneMarker()` method. Should i change it? I am using the static method for instancing but in the `DatabaseHandler` class i am using the SQLITEDatabase. Is that the problem?

Comment: I am not allowed to use `DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);` or `getApplicationContext()` in `DatabaseHandler` class. Only in main activity. Sorry im quite new to android. :/ i meant the `context` is the problem, not the whole line.  `getApplicationContext()` i can use only in MainActivity and it works with the new method but i can't call it in DatabaseHandler. Wont accept the Context.

Comment: Can you post your SQLite Helper class? It is supposed to allow `DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);` from anywhere with a valid `context` parameter. what do u mean by u are not allowed? is it showing any error? if it shows, let me know the error. @fixxxera

Comment: Please post the revised code in main question. Also if possible put code how you are calling the helper.

Comment: Posted edit (again). I am calling database class in `onPostExecute()`in async subclass in MainActivity and in `onMarkerClick()` to retrieve the info for display in another activity

Comment: Remove the `assert curs != null;` line in addMarker() and also remove condition `if (result>0){
            db.close();
        }` in getOneMarker. You must call db.close() after each operation. Try and let me know. Also update the code.

Comment: Updated `onMarkerClick()` and `onPostExecute()` with your suggestion. Also edited `addMarker()` and `getOneMarker()` with latest versions. Via debugging i saw that the marker is getting saved in DB every time using the rowid that `insert()` method returns. This is as far as i went. The problem is now i get 70% error margin.

Comment: remove super.onPostExecute(markers);. i still see condition i have asked to remove.

Comment: Also i tried `Toast`-ing the object `marker` before insertion into DB and still getting the street name correctly. So its either problem during saving(sync problem) or it is when i extract it from DB. Working on it ATM.

Comment: just removed it. No change. Most of them throw `NullPointer` when extracting Address line

Comment: Ok - update. I get the null pointer when adding several markers on map and after that i click them to check the address.if i put one marker and then check it i get the address(at least for now). Also app performance significantly decreased.So i guess this leaves sync as a possible problem...

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your design. I will higly recommend you to see how basic lat lng are retrieved by standard projects. Google it. hope you will get some clue.